# Php 8.3 No active Transaction in Laravel 8

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-8, php-8.3

Once it reaches `DB::commit`, it throws an error. However, if I comment out the `Schema::table` code, it works in PHP 8.3. In PHP 7.3, it still works as expected.

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
  // performing some model::create() operations 
    if(!empty($table)){
        Schema::table($table, function (Blueprint $table) use ($newProfileField) {
            $column_type = isset($newProfileField->fieldType) ? $newProfileField- >fieldType->sql_column_type : 'string';
            $table->$column_type($newProfileField->field_name)->nullable();
        });
    
}

    DB::commit();
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
   DB::rollback();
}
```

This is happening once I upgraded my PHP version to 8.3
PDOException. There is no active transaction.

Comment: Is your code correct? Because you have one `}` too many just before the `DB::commit()`

Comment: With mysql this code will never work, table creation automatically commits a transction. It "worked" with 7.3 probably because the table already existed and this code just never run

Comment: Laravel 8 doesn't support PHP 8.3 (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases). If you say the PHP update caused the issue, that might be the origin.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you even using, if I may ask? `Schema` only existed until version 5.x.. While you don't use the transaction which you started, unless using `DB` methods there, too. Something about this question seems to be wrong: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/schema

Comment: @MartinZeitler Schema still exists, and is used when creating migrations. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#migration-structure and https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/migrations#introduction

Comment: @vixducis so what could be the solution for this as i also have a project in laravel 10.x on same server